# cannot grab firebase storage files

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to allow use the react reader app to show epubs, but it fails when loading firebase storage urls. I tried setting the CORS to * and that fixed one of the issues, not there's another, I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have your read/write rules updated for storage?

Comment: or if you can share the code